# Crontab not running second command

Tags: python-3.x, cron, raspberry-pi

I have the following two lines in crontab. I expect the first line to start my python script 30 seconds after boot, and the second line to kill and restart the script every two minutes.

```
@reboot (/bin/sleep 30; /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/Desktop/file.py > /home/pi/Desktop/logfile 2>&1)

*/2 * * * * (kill $(pgrep -f 'python3 -u /home/pi/Desktop/file.py'); /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/Desktop/file.py > /home/pi/Desktop/logfile 2>&1)
```

The script does run correctly upon boot and the script is killed two minutes later, but the script is not restarted by the second line. I don't believe it is a syntax error, because if I copy the second line directly into terminal (without the */2 * * * *), it properly kills and restarts the script. Why does this line work in terminal, but not in crontab?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no need for the parentheses around your commands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but it seems that crontab will not execute any other commands in the same line after the 'kill $()' command.
I discovered this by placing printf commands to a log file before an after the kill command, but only the one before kill ended up in the log. I removed the kill command but left pgrep in its place, which resulted in the first printf text, the PID number, and the second printf text in the log.
My work around was just to place the two commands in a shell file, and have crontab run the shell. Seems to work just fine.